# TOTP and Diffie-Hellman key exchange using Java

Tags: java, authentication, diffie-hellman, one-time-password

I would like to ask how do I carry out a client server application that could do the operations of one time password and diffie hellman key exchange at the same time using java? The scenario is that the one time password is to be encrypted using the diffie hellman shared keys. The client will then send the encrypted OTP to the server and the server checks if it matches with the one it generates. I am not sure if the operations can be carried out together

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to execute hellman key exchange and generate shared secret key between server and client. then after client take the key and perform encryption using shared secret key with some encryption algorithm and send it to server server decrypt the data. so you can generate shared secrete key one time for all encryption or you can generate all time. but i can suggest you use asymmetric key cryptography(RSA, ECC) it will reduce overhead of  hellman key exchange. and it will more secure as compare with symmetric key cryptography.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I wanted to use diffie hellman to mutually authenticated the server and client using the encrypted otp. May I know how do I execute the server and client on Java? Should I use socket for the sending of otp or is there another way? Do I create classes of the diffie hellman operation and one time password operation and call them in the server and client application? Sorry I'm not familiar with Java and still learning how to code using it. Thank you for your answer :)